# Can I use var(--my-color) in @if condition in scss?

Tags: sass

I set a style property on body when the page loaded. Just like:

```
document
  .getElementsByTagName("body")[0]
  .style.setProperty("--is-app", isApp ? 1 : 2);
```

And in my .scss file, I write this:

```
 $isApp: var(--is-app);
 @if $isApp == 1 {
  do something...
 }
 @else{
  do something...
 }
```

But it did't work as I want.
Is this because of that the scss is pre-processor not runtime one?

Finally I change it by using different class name.

But I wonder if I missed something in scss? Is it possible to make it work just by scss syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Sass is compiled on the server before it's sent to the browser. When it's being compiled, there is no `document` and front-end javascript doesn't run, so `--is-app` isn't defined.